# Unhandled promise rejection warning in Ethereum

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I am very much struggling to find the solution to  my problem. I am receiving errors:

[image: Error Snippet]

```
for (address in accountAddress) {
            try {
              let code = await web3.eth.getCode(address)
              //myCode.....
              
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err)
            }
          }
```

Comment: Can anyone help please? I am not getting the solution. After going through 90 % of iteration i am loosing all the data.

Comment: How do you initialize `web3`? Are you sure it is initialized correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have done it correctly.
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));


Also, I have tried with infura
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/myKey'));

Comment: Everything works fine. But suddenly this error comes (UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning) and I lose all my data.

I am using web3@0.20.1 version

Comment: @ash if you're using version 0.2x.x of web3 you web3.eth.getCode is sent asynchronously by default, so you wouldn't need the await statement https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode. Otherwise, are you sure the addresses you're using are correct?

Comment: Hey Rosco, i am pretty sure with the addresses. Because, when i am iterating through 100 blocks, i am getting all the data I need without any problem. But when i am iterating for a long range of blocks (lets say 50000), I am getting an error. I have even got this error after iterating 48000 blocks. Even if i do without await, how would it actually matter? The problem statement is- i have to get all the contract addresses ever made on ethereum network. And i am struggling big time because of this error. I have gone through many recommendations but nothing worked, required help.

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: Perhaps you're being rate limited in some way, since you're doing so many calls one after another. Could you try storing the data up until where it works and then later picking up again from that point. i.e. do it in batches.